# Angular Storybook ngTemplateOutlet problem

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm currently implementing a storybook to document my design system, but i can't find ou how to create a story for this component. I'm explaining my problem :
Here is my component which is a select component :

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'wgw-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss']
})
export class SelectComponent<T extends {id: string | number}> {
 
  @Input() itemTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() items: T[];
  @Input() selectedItem: T;
  @Output() selectedItemChange: EventEmitter<T> = new EventEmitter<T>();
 
  selectValue(newValue: T) {
    this.selectedItem = newValue;
    this.selectedItemChange.emit(this.selectedItem);
  }
 
  equals(item1: T, item2: T) {
    return item1?.id === item2?.id
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="fs-4" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="this.itemTemplate; context: {item: selectedItem}"></ng-container>
    <wgw-icon name="chevron-down" class="ms-4"></wgw-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu mt-5" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <div class="dropdown-item fs-4" *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="selectValue(item)" [class.selected]="equals(selectedItem, item)">
      <wgw-icon [name]="'check'" *ngIf="equals(selectedItem, item)" class="me-4"></wgw-icon>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="this.itemTemplate; context: {item: item}"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the story i've created so far

```js
import {SelectComponent} from '@design-system/atom/select/select.component';
import {moduleMetadata, Story} from '@storybook/angular';
import {IconComponent} from '@design-system/atom/icon/icon.component';
 
export default {
  title: 'Atom/Select',
  component: SelectComponent,
  args: {
 
  },
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [IconComponent]
    }),
  ],
}
 
const Template: Story<SelectComponent<any>> = (args) => ({
  props: args,
  template: `
    <div>
        <ng-template #itemTestTemplate let-item="item">
          {{ item?.name }}
        </ng-template>
        <wgw-select [items]="items" [itemTemplate]="itemTestTemplate"></wgw-select>
    </div>
  `
})
 
export const Select = Template.bind({});
Select.args = {
  items: [
    {id: 0, name: 'item1'},
    {id: 1, name: 'item2'},
    {id: 2, name: 'item3'}
  ],
  selectedItem: {id: 0, name: 'item1'}
}
```

The problem i have is this : i'm passing my template to my component with this `[itemTemplate]="itemTestTemplate"` but it seems this template have no access to the "item" in my storybook.

Do you know where this problem can come from ? And how i can fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Can you post the exact error message? As a sidenote, I've written a directive [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/datatable/src/row-template/row-template.directive.ts#L10) that can be used [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/datatables/datatables.component.html#L13), which keeps the page html clean

Comment: Nothing, it just display nothing. And if i remove the ?. for a simple . of the {{ item?.name }} i have a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

So it appears that my itemTestTemplate never have an item ...

Comment: Strange, However you can always double-check using `{{ item | json }}`. Try both below the `<wgw-icon>` and inside your `<ng-template>`

Comment: With this code 


template: `
    {{ items | json }}
    <div>
        <ng-template #itemTestTemplate let-item="item">
          {{ item | json }}
        </ng-template>
        <wgw-select [items]="items" [itemTemplate]="itemTestTemplate"></wgw-select>
    </div>
  `


I just got the same thing : 
I see the json of all the items, but in the component, this {{ item | json }} is just empty

Comment: Hmm perhaps it's caused by `ngTemplateOutlet="this.itemTemplate`. To replace with `ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate`

Comment: Recreating it now in StackBlitz and just noticed it. [This example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ayaub?file=src/app/app.component.html) works as expected...

Comment: But this example does not include any story of storybook. Or did i missed something ?

Comment: Because my component is working well in the app, it's when i'm trying to create a story with it that it doesn't work anymore

Comment: No it's just a very rough reproduction.